# How to use vec2 in android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I try using

vec2
sin
fract

for pseudo random number generation and dont know which imports I should use

I do have:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;
```

But they are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then you can press control + shift + o and it will automatically import everything if you aren't using eclipse I recommend it